# encodeURIComponent() ignoring line breaks

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to encode a string from a textarea so I can output the encoded result for a mailto link. Spaces and special characters are encoded fine but line break aren't, they just get encoded as a space. 
 How do I encode my line breaks?

```
if (id == 'subject' || id == 'body') {
            let str = output.innerText;
            str = encodeURIComponent(str);
            // str = str.replace(/\n/g, "%0A").replace(/ /g, "%20").replace(/&/g, "%26");
            output.innerText = str;
        }
```

I've also tried this which doesn't work either:

```
str = encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/\n/g, '%0D%0A');
```

Here's how my output currently looks:

```
mailto:mckeever02@gmail.com?body=Testing%20Should%20be%20a%20line%20break%20before%20this%20sentence
```

Notice that line breaks are just being encoded to `%20` (space). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Line breaks are replaced with `%0A`. Get the text from textarea with `value` and not `innerHTML`/`innerText`

```js
const ta = document.getElementById("ta");
const val = ta.value;

console.log(encodeURIComponent(val));
```

```html
<textarea id="ta">
First line
Second line
</textarea>
```

Comment: Yes. `.value` exists for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

See my example snippet.
Im just reading data from textarea using innerHtml to have new lines available and use simple encodeURIComponent. New lines are transfered to `%0A` and spaces to 
`%20`

Probably your problem was to use innerText instead of innerHTML. innerText not taking new lines.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('textarea').innerHTML;
console.log(encodeURIComponent(text))
```

```html
<textarea>
Test
aaaa
bbbb ccc
dddd
</textarea>
```